# i need to click on the iframe video

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i need to click on this iframe video,

```
<div class="videoWrapper" style="" xpath="1"> 
<iframe width="854" height="480" src="xxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>
```

Code for switching to frame

```
driver.switchto().frame("videoWrapper");
```

i tried with these Logic's ,

Logic 1 :

```
WebElement video = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='player_uid_840828282_1']/div[4]/div[1]"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].play();", video);
```

Logic 2 :

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js .executeScript("document.getElementById(\"video\").play()");
```

But it is not Working , please clear me this out guys!

Comment: driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")); then write your logic

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(0); if u have two or more then 0,1,2...

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.ClassName("videoWrapper")));

Comment: `videoWrapper` is the style class of a div, not an iframe ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code to switch to required frame:

```
driver.switchto().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='videoWrapper']/iframe")));
```

Also note that you cannot apply `play()` to `div` node, but to `video` node (e.g. `<video></video>`)

Comment: Thanks man, now it switched to that frame, but without using play() how i can play the video?

Comment: Depends on the element you need to handle. Is it `video` node? Share HTML for video-player also

Comment: Yes, it is youtube video which they uploaded in the site . For That they have used iframe.

Comment: @koushick If it is a Youtube video, try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label='Play']").click()`

Comment: it is not working, but anyway thanks it switched to frame. Let Me Try with javascripexecutor and tell you!

Answer (score -1):

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")));
```

Comment: iframe has no class name attribute

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.